# How can I unwrap an Rc, obtained by Weak::upgrade, having more than one strong references?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement an linked list for learning purposes and a feature I'm implementing now is **fn pop_back** which is to pop data in the last location in my linked list instance. RefCell, Rc and Weak are mainly used to store data into the list.

Here is my code (**fn pop_back** is at the bottom of the code) :

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::{Rc, Weak};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct DbNode<T> {
    data: T,
    next: Option<Rc<RefCell<DbNode<T>>>>,
    prev: Option<Weak<RefCell<DbNode<T>>>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct DbList<T> {
    first: Option<Rc<RefCell<DbNode<T>>>>,
    last: Option<Weak<RefCell<DbNode<T>>>>,
}

impl<T> DbList<T> {

    pub fn new() -> Self {
        DbList {
            first: None,
            last: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn push_front(&mut self, data: T) {
        match self.first.take() {
            Some(e) => {
                let new_front = Rc::new(RefCell::new(DbNode {
                    data,
                    next: Some(e.clone()),
                    prev: None,
                }));
                let mut me = e.borrow_mut();
                me.prev = Some(Rc::downgrade(&new_front));
                self.first = Some(new_front);
            },
            None => {
                let new_data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(DbNode {
                    data,
                    next: None,
                    prev: None,
                }));
                self.last = Some(Rc::downgrade(&new_data));
                self.first = Some(new_data);
            },
        }
    }

    pub fn push_back(&mut self, data: T) {
        match self.last.take() {
            Some(l) => {
                let new_back = Rc::new(RefCell::new(DbNode {
                    data,
                    next: None,
                    prev: Some(l.clone()),
                }));
                let st = Weak::upgrade(&l).unwrap();
                let mut ml = st.borrow_mut();
                self.last = Some(Rc::downgrade(&new_back));
                ml.next = Some(new_back);
            },
            None => {
                let new_data = Rc::new(RefCell::new(DbNode {
                    data,
                    next: None,
                    prev: None,
                }));
                self.last = Some(Rc::downgrade(&new_data));                
                self.first = Some(new_data);
            },
        }
    }

    pub fn pop_front(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        match self.first.take() {
            Some(first) => {
                match Rc::try_unwrap(first) {
                    Ok(refc) => {
                        let inner = refc.into_inner();
                        self.first = inner.next;
                        if let None = self.first {
                            self.last = None;
                        };
                        Some(inner.data)
                    },
                    Err(_) => None,
                }
            },
            None => None,
        }
    }

    pub fn pop_back(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        match self.last.take() {
            Some(last) => {
                // todo: try_unwrap goes to err: the 'prev' in the 'last' holding the reference of this?
                match Rc::try_unwrap(Weak::upgrade(&last).unwrap()) {
                    Ok(refc) => {
                        let inner = refc.into_inner();
                        self.last = inner.prev;
                        Some(inner.data)
                    },
                    Err(_) => None,
                }
            },
            None => None,
        }
    }
}
```

the **fn pop_back** should return the last DbNode if possible, and set the 'next' DbNode in the previous DbNode of the existing 'last' to the 'new last'. So I need to unwrap the existing to obtain the previous DbNode, which is going to be the new last. But Rc::try_unwrap goes to Err. I guess this is because the existing last itself is an Weak, so it already has one strong reference and the reference count increases with **Rc::try_unwrap(Weak::upgrade(&last).unwrap())**. I'm not 100% sure of my guess.

What should I do for it?

## Completed

I've done this based on the approach suggested by @Masklinn. In addition to the approach, before **Rc::try_unwrap**, I just have to drop an Rc held by the 'first' field in DbList when the list has only one DbNode left, since the 'prev' field has **None** when only one DbNode is left in the list. It meets the same error I faced first, without dropping the 'first'.

Here is the final code on **fn pop_back** written:

```
pub fn pop_back(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
    match self.last.take() {
        Some(last) => {
            let last = Weak::upgrade(&last).unwrap();
            if Rc::ptr_eq(self.first.as_ref().unwrap(), &last) {
                self.first = None;
            } else {
                let prev = Weak::upgrade(last.borrow().prev.as_ref().unwrap());
                prev.as_ref().unwrap().borrow_mut().next = None;
                self.last = Some(Rc::downgrade(prev.as_ref().unwrap()));                  
            }
            match Rc::try_unwrap(last) {
                Ok(iv) => Some(iv.into_inner().data),
                Err(_) => None,
            }                  
        },
        None => None,
    }
}
```

Comment: Mandatory reading if you haven't already: [Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I guess this is because the existing last itself is an Weak, so it already has one strong reference and the reference count increases

This scheme of using weak references is really weird (that's not really what they're for), but here what you need to do is:

- take from last()
- upgrade last(), creating the second Rc
- follow its prev() link to the second-to-last
- set that as the new last
- take from second-to-last's next, that's the first / existing Rc
- drop either the upgraded value or the one you got from second-to-last, they're both strong references to the former `last`, this will leave you with a refcount of 1
- which means you can unwrap it

You can't unwrap the Rc before the last step, because it will always have two strong refs before that.

Something along the lines of this:

```rust
    pub fn pop_back(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        self.last.take().and_then(|last| {
            // get a strong reference of last
            let last = Weak::upgrade(&last).expect("Last element of the list was already deallocated.");
            // get a strong reference of second-to-last
            let prev = last.borrow().prev.as_ref().and_then(Weak::upgrade).expect("Previous-to-last element of the list was already deallocated");
            // remove the old last from the new last
            prev.borrow_mut().next = None;
            // set second to last as the new last
            self.last = Some(Rc::downgrade(&prev));
            // extract the old last's payload and return it
            Rc::try_unwrap(last).ok().map(|v| v.into_inner().data)
        })
    }
```

I swapped setting the new last and updating its next because that way all the things which *must* succeed (should only panic if the data structure is in an incoherent state) will run before we perform the first new mutation. Then we do all the mutation using in ways which should not be failable, so we should have no "panic hole".

I also just set its `next` to `None` directly, since we already have a strong reference on last we just care that the old one gets destroyed.

Comment: @Maskilinn In your steps, how can it be possible to set the second-to-last as the new last? The only way to get the second-to-last I know is `rc.borrow_mut().prev.unwrap()`, but it causes compiler error: &quot;cannot move out of dereference of RefMut...&quot;. Also, Its reference cannot be set as the new last because the type of the new last expected is an owned value, not a reference.

Comment: I mean these are not really *my* steps, this is what you must do according to how you designed your data structure. And of course you don't try to move the second-to-last out of a mutable ref. You don't even need a mutable ref: `rc.borrow().prev.as_ref().map(Weak::clone)`. This way you create a new `Option<Weak<_>>` from the existing one, which you can set as the new value for the last pointer.

Comment: I added a snippet which should be roughly what you want. It should be close to working if it doesn't work as-is.

Comment: @Masklinn you should make `prev` an `Option<Rc>` and drop the `.expect()`, its expected to not have a `prev` if there's only one element in the list

Comment: @kmdreko ah yes, probably got a bit lost in my refactorings when I figured some of the options really should be unwrapped because they denoted a broken datastructure. And I probably only tested it with lists of multiple elements/

Comment: Though I also forgot to update `first` in that specific case so I guess panicing is less bad than corrupting the structure?